# Hadoop webapps - yarn UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

what is the webserver that Yarn UI runs on Resource manager master server?

logs under `/var/log/httpd/access_log` doest provide any information, i couldnt able to find any other logs with the access information on YarnUI

yarn runs on single master EMR cluster (http://master-Server-IP:8088/cluster )

Comment: Jetty, according to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/dependency-analysis.html